# How to Play audio file for 60 minutes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating an app to play some relaxing sounds, now I want the user to specify how long he wants the sounds to play. My audio clip is just 10minutes clip, say the user wants it to play for 60mins, which means it will repeat 6 times.

I have used both for and do-while combined with if statement and yet the sound will only play and stop once it ends.

Comment: Okay, all points noted.

Comment: `I have used both for and do-while combined with if statement and yet the sound will only play and stop once it ends.`; Can you show the code that you have implemented so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unity `AudioSource` has a property called loop: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-loop.html.

You can set your `AudioSource` to loop until the time is over. When the time is over, you just need to call the method `Stop()`.

```
public class AudioHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioSource source;
    public float duration;

    Start(){
        source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void StartPlaying(){
        source.loop = true;      //this will make the audio loop forever
        source.Play();
        Invoke("StopPlaying", duration);
    }

    public void StopPlaying(){
        source.Stop();
    }
}
```

Note that your `GameObject` must have an `AudioSource` attached to it, with the `AudioClip` set inside the `AudioSource`.

Comment: Awesome, It worked. So I used it with an array of songs as shown below and it worked perfectly for me. Thanks man!

Comment: How do I add a snippet of the code here as I noticed what I am adding is quite more than allowable. Is there a special way to add the codes?

Comment: You just need to write it as a `MonoBehaviour` class in a `GameObject`. I edited my answer.